# Can $(\mu_1 - \mu)^2 + (\mu_2 - \mu)^2$ be simplified to remove $\mu?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are means of two groups, while $\mu$ is the overall mean.

I feel like this can be done with some basic algebra I've forgotten, but I'm not sure.

Here is some more context:

$$
f = \frac{\sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{j}{(\mu_j - \mu)^{2}}}{J}}}{\sigma_{y}}
$$
which with two groups (J=2) reduces to:
$$
f = \frac{\sqrt{\dfrac{(\mu_{1} - \mu)^{2} + (\mu_{2} - \mu)^{2}}{2}}}{\sigma_{y}}
$$

Comment: You're pretty much stuck. The value of that expression depends on what $\mu$ is.

Comment: What if I add a square root around the whole thing? I moved that to the other side of the equation before I posted.

Comment: If the value of something depends on $\mu$ then so will its square root. Could you explain why you want to remove $\mu$, the context might help us answer your question.

Comment: You can do it if you have the sizes of the two groups.  See my answer below. $\qquad$

Comment: BTW, so far I'm the only one who's up-voted the question. $\qquad$

Comment: You have a rather weird idea of what *context* is, Matt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n_1$ and $n_2$ be the respective sizes of the two groups.  Then
$$
\mu = \frac{n_1\mu_1+n_2\mu_2}{n_1+n_2}.
$$
And then we have
\begin{align}
& (\mu_1 - \mu)^2 + (\mu_2 - \mu)^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & \left( \frac{(n_1+n_2)\mu_1-(n_1\mu_1+n_2\mu_2)}{n_1+n_2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{(n_1+n_2)\mu_2-(n_1\mu_1+n_2\mu_2)}{n_1+n_2} \right)^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\Big(n_2(\mu_1-\mu_2)\Big)^2}{n_1+n_2} + \frac{\Big(n_1(\mu_2-\mu_1)\Big)^2}{n_1+n_2} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{(n_1^2+n_2^2)(\mu_2-\mu_2)^2}{n_1+n_2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, I think this is it. And in this case the group sizes should be equal (forgot to mention that) which should simplify the algebra considerably!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we can remove $\mu$.  If we could, then the expression would be unchanged if we plugged various values in for $\mu$.  for instance $$\begin{align}
    \mu &= 0 &&:  & (\mu_1 - 0)^2 + (\mu_2 - 0)^2 &= \mu_1^2 + \mu_2^2 \\
    \mu &= \mu_1 &&:  & (\mu_1 - \mu_1)^2 + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)^2 &= \mu_1^2 -2 \mu_1\mu_2 + \mu_2^2 \\
    \mu &= \mu_2 &&:  & (\mu_1 - \mu_2)^2 + (\mu_2 - \mu_2)^2 &= \mu_1^2 -2 \mu_1 \mu_2 + \mu_2^2 \\
\end{align}$$

Since these aren't all the same, and the only thing we did was change the value of $\mu$, we can't find an expression that doesn't contain $\mu$ that takes the same values.

Comment: I believe you're mistaken; see my answer. $\qquad$

Comment: @micheal, your answer depends on guessing a few things that the OP does not tell us. Eric's answer is a perfectly correct answer for the question as written.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez You're technically right because I wasn't explicit about there _only_ being two groups, but I did say there were two groups. It isn't too much of a leap to treat them as the only two groups.

Comment: @MattChambers : The jump from "there exist two groups" to "there exist exactly two groups" is farther than most strong answerers on this site will make without substantial evidence from the original post.  That an incomplete question has an incomplete answer should not come as any great surprise.